# Creating a remote database that can validate user login credential request

Tags: java, mysql

I have created a java program that has a login screen. It takes two inputs, discordID and key.

The discordID and key are located inside of an JSON file that is automatically updated by a Discord bot that i have. The bot is made in Python.

I want to use MySQL for handling the user login requests. So my question is...
Can i open up the server for public and handle user login requests? And if that works i want to return True or False depending if the credetials match the ones in the DataBase.

Was thinking at mongoDB for example. There you can return True or False depending if the credentials from the user equals to the ones you have in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible if you create another app just to accept this info over RESTful API but my concern is a different one. Have you given a thought how you would transfer the ID and Key. Are you planning on setting up SSL/HTTPS because that's what you would need to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: So does RESTful hold the data or does it need to be linked to the DataBase (i.e MySql)? Right now i just want to get the user validation to work, and then think of securing it. This is just a small side project I am working on.

Comment: And if the user were to notice that their login credentials have been tampered with they have the option to request for a new key, and that is done by the discord.py bot.